# Map of spectra induced by $\mathbb{C}[t] \to \mathbb{C}[t]$, $t \mapsto t^2$ (Vakil's Rising Sea, 3.2.O)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification

In Vakil's ‘Rising Sea’, exercise 3.2.O goes (edited for brevity):

> Consider the map of complex manifolds sending $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ via $x \mapsto y = x^2$. Interpret the corresponding map of rings as given by $\mathbb{C}[y] \to  \mathbb{C}[x]$ by $y \mapsto  x^2$.

Here is my solution:

Consider $f: \mathbb{C}[y] \to  \mathbb{C}[x]$ where $f(y) = x^2$. Then the induced map $f^{\ast}: \mathrm{Spec} \, \mathbb{C}[x] \to  \mathrm{Spec}\, \mathbb{C}[y]$ is given by $[\mathfrak p] \longmapsto [f^{-1}(\mathfrak p)]$. We have to prove that $f^\ast((x-a)) = (y-a^2)$. Since $f(y-a^2) = (x-a)(x+a) \subseteq (x - a)$, we have one side of the inclusion.

Now suppose $q(y) = \sum b_k y^k \in \mathbb{C}[y]$ and $f(q(y)) = \sum b_k x^{2k} = (x-a)p(x)$ for some polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$. Since $\sum b_k a^{2k} = (a-a)p(a) = 0$, we have $\sum b_k (a^2)^k = 0$, and thus $q(a^2) = 0$ and $q(y) \in (y-a^2)$.

Is my proof correct? And how could I improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your proof works.

Alternatively you can argue as follows: The ideal $(y-a^2) \subset \Bbb C[y]$ is a maximal ideal, so $y-a^2 \in f^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$ shows $(y-a^2) = f^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$, since $f^{-1}(\mathfrak p) \neq \Bbb C[y]$.